# Toggle/close all other divs when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

everyone.

Need help to close all other divs when one is clicked. Thanks in advance!

Bellow is the code:

=============================

## JS

```
$(".dis-nav a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var myClass=$(this).attr("id");
//  alert(myClass);
$(".dis-content ."+myClass).toggle('fast');
});
```

=============================

## HTML

```
<div class="dis-nav button">
<a href="#" id="area1">Firefox</a> 
<a href="#" id="area2">Safari</a> 
<a href="#" id="area3">Chrome</a> 
<a href="#" id="area4">IE</a> 
</div>

<div class="dis-content">
<div class="area1">
<h3>Firefox</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area2">
<h3>Safari</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area3">
<h3>Chrome</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
<div class="area4">
<h3>IE</h3>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Morbi ac felis nec mauris imperdiet fermentum. Aenean sodales augue ac lacus hendrerit sed rhoncus erat hendrerit. Vivamus vel ultricies elit. Aliquam ut feugiat ante. Curabitur lacinia nulla vel tellus elementum non mollis justo aliquam.</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> Buy</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">TryMais</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, as my predecessor said, you should try to describe your problem giving us more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".dis-nav a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
    //  alert(myClass);
    $('.dis-content div').hide();
    $(".dis-content ." + myClass).show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pY2tE/)

If you want to hide the entire block intially, and show just the first by default:

```
$(function(){
    $('.dis-content div').hide()
    $('.dis-content .area1').show()

    $(".dis-nav a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myClass = $(this).attr("id");
        //  alert(myClass);
        $('.dis-content div').hide();
        $(".dis-content ." + myClass).show();
    });
    $(".dis-nav #show-all").click(function (e) {
        $('.dis-content div').show()
    });
});
```

I shall let you figure out the css, and other minor details yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Just another doubt... Is it possible to have another link to show all?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. On click, just do `$('.dis-content div').show()`

Comment: Like this? <a href="#" onClick="$('.dis-content div').show()">See all</a>

Comment: No  a jquery listener

Comment: Could you, please, give me an example?

Comment: I have edited the answer. I would highly recommend you taking a few minutes to understand what is going on. That way, you dont get stuck again on basic stuff. For advanced stuff, SO is always there to help you :)

Comment: Thanks again and sorry to bother! This is my first time here! ;-)